# i want to create a matrix of matrixes in Octave

Tags: matrix, octave

i have set some matrixes and i want to put them in one matrix with name "A"

The following is the code that i use and it gives me an error at the last line.
But when i select only the RIGHT PART of the equation of the last command, i am getting what i expect

```
s(1)=0.08;
s(2)=0.14;
s(3)=0.40;
p(1,2)=p(2,1)=0.5;
p(1,3)=p(3,1)=-0.15;
p(2,3)=p(3,2)=0.25;
C=[];%====creation of covarange matrix=============
for i=1:3
  for j=1:3
if i==j
  S(i,j)=s(i)^2;
else
  S(i,j) = p(i,j)*s(i)*s(j);
endif  
C(i,j)=S(i,j);
endfor
end%=======definition of "m" matrix======
m=[0.04;0.08;0.15];
aces=ones(3,1);
Α=[C,-m,aces;m',0,0;aces',0,0]`
```

Comment: The only error that I get is that the `A` at the beginning of that line is a unicode upper-case Alpha rather than an upper-case A. Fix that and you should be good.

Comment: Please copy-paste the full error message into your post. “Gives me an error at the last line” is not nearly enough information. I have no idea where to start looking. @beaker had to run the code themselves to know what the error message was. Most people here will not be sufficiently interested in your problem to do so.

Answer (score 2):

As beaker said, you used a greek 'A', and octave complains because non-ASCII characters are not supported in octave code for variables (yet); though they can be used in strings and comments, obviously.

However, I'm creating an answer here also to point out your code could be simplified greatly to consist of matrix operations instead of scalar ones, like so:

```
S1   = repmat( [0.08, 0.14, 0.4], 3, 1 );
S2   = S1.';
P    = [1, 0.5, -0.15; 0.5, 1, 0.25; -0.15, 0.25, 1];
C    = S1 .* S2 .* P;
m    = [0.04; 0.08; 0.15];
aces = ones(3, 1);
A    = [C, -m, aces; m', 0, 0; aces', 0, 0]'
```